# add vertical flexible space between UIButton in iphone app on ios 4.3 or more

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

i have 12 UIButton in a UIView lineup as 2 buttons on each horizontally, these buttons can be hidden or shown dynamically according to availability of information.

The problem is that when a button is in hidden state, I want to fill that empty space upward with the next available button dynamically. the app is going to run on iOS version 4.3 or greater so I cannot use the Auto-layouts. Please provide answer with some suitable example.

Comment: give code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be when you are hiding a button move all other buttons by giving setting their rects to adjacent button's rect.

For example if you have 4 buttons and button1 is hidden do like this in a loop:

```
 CGRect tempRect = button2.rect;
 button2.rect = button1.rect;//repeat this in a loop for all available buttons.
```